# Coding Two buttons with the same function but different classes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so that one of the tabs on my portfolio website creates a drop down menu. I was able to make it so that when people click on the picture, it makes a dropdown menu. However, I also wanted the same thing to happen when they click on the text as well. So my problem is that I have two buttons with different classes that I want to have the same function. I thought I could do that with the javascript I have now, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's a link to a porotype I created https://iancoffman.com/digitalart2.html. The code should be viewable publicly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What code are you using for your drop down menu that you want to show when clicking? You could use basic JavaScript to trigger the same function when you click each item.

A basic function example would be:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

You could attach this function to a div that contains both the text and image like:

```
<div onclick="myFunction()">
  <p>Text To Click.</p>
  <img src="images/paint-symbol.png" alt="paintings">
</div>
<div id="menu" style="display:none;">Dropdown Menu</div>
```

Or you could add this function to each item if they are not connected:

```
<p onclick="myFunction()">Text To Click.</p>
<img src="images/paint-symbol.png" alt="paintings" onclick="myFunction()">
<div id="menu" style="display:none;">Dropdown Menu</div>
```

Not sure what exactly you are trying for but this might get you started with the concept.